# Using AJAX and JSON to display HTML content from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to retrieve information from my php file which contains the following code. My code contains the colums Email, FirstName, LastName, and State.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(Email) = :email';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $firstName = $row['FirstName'];
    $lastName = $row['LastName'];
    $state = $row['State'];     
} echo json_encode($row);
```

My Ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
    datatype: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    url: 'json-data.php',         
      success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
        $('#firstname').append(data.FirstName);     
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }
```

});

When I type `$('#firstname').append(data);`, it shows me the following output:

```
{"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","State":"Florida","Email":"foo@bar.com"}
```

How do I make it so I can get only the first name and append it to a div?

Comment: Your code looks correct. What specifically is not working?

Comment: It doesn't display when I append using `$('#firstname').append(data.FirstName);`
but it does when I use `$('#firstname').append(data);` but this method outputs the entire array when I am only looking for one element.

Comment: I found my error, instead of `dataType`, I was using `datatype`... >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$('#firstname').append(OBJ.FirstName);
```

Comment: Had to make an edit to have it work but it did. Thank you very much.
$('#firstname').append(obj.FirstName);  
Is there a way to do it without parsing it again like Sedz said?

Comment: I found my error, instead of 'dataType', I was using 'datatype'